# Ruby - constantize in certain directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In an application, I have a method that gets the name of a policy for a certain ActiveRecord as follows:

```
def policy_for(record:)
  "#{record.class}Policy".constantize.new(record)
end
```

This works perfectly, except in one case where I have a model and a policy having the same name. This line then returns the model, and not the policy.

In other words, **Problem: Multiple classes have the same name.**

**Goal: Need a constantize alternative that gets the class but in a certain directory, or has a certain superclass for example (BasePolicy instead of ActiveRecord).**

How can I do this in Ruby?

Comment: It's not about "different classes with the same name" (that is impossible in Ruby), it is about constant lookup machinery and lexical contexts. Try using a fully qualified class name starting from the outermost lexical context (`"::#{record.class}Policy".constantize...` etc) - it should fix the issue for you...

Comment: neither class is under any module, is there a way to do this using just the directory or the superclass?

Comment: Sometimes "impossible" means just impossible. If you defined your policy class with exactly the same name as one of your model classes in the same outermost lexical scope - there is **no** way to make it work. Don't believe me? Load rails console and try to require your policy class explicitly - you will get `superclass mismatch` error (because at this moment your model classes will be loaded already and your conflicting `<Whatever>Policy` class will have AR::Base/ApplicationRecord/etc as its ancestor)

Comment: Okk lets say I wrap my policy class in a module Policy, what next? :D

Comment: If you use a module `Policy` then your class would be `"::Policy::#{record.class}Policy".safe_constantize&.new(record)`.

Answer (score 2):

1 - Don't have classes with similar names under the same module.

2 - In rails, models will be the outermost context. So consider moving your policies under a `Policies` namespace. That will solve your issue right and similar other issues down the road.

Comment: To add to this, Rails will expose your code in `app/` at the outermost context (`::MyModelName`, `::MyControllerName`) and any gems you have will expose *their* libraries in the outermost context (`::ActiveRecord`, `::ActiveSupport`), and so putting your custom/non-standard classes and modules into their own namespace (`::Policies::MyCustomClass`) separates them and allows you to re-use names to give semantic meaning to your app. For example, a model `::Users` in `app/models/user.rb` and a class `::Policies::User` in `app/lib/policies/user.rb` gives semantic meaning.